# Owl Carousel items option based on items count

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel, items

How can I do something like this?

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    items: function (e) {
        if (e.item.count <= e.page.size) {
            return e.item.count;
        }
    }
});
```

I also spend a lot of time on `initialized.owl.carousel` event but have had no success.

```
owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function (e) {
    if (e.item.count <= e.page.size) {
        owl.data('owl.carousel').options.items = e.item.count;
    }
});
```

Btw I put this before `owl.owlCarousel`

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: It's not obvious?